# Unable to Update Global State for Redux Flow in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement the Redux state in SwiftUI and I am stuck with updating the global state after the action creator has been executed. I am lost as what to do in the Store dispatch function.

```
// Store.swift 

typealias ActionCreator = (_ dispatch: @escaping (Action) -> ()) -> ()

func getMovies() -> ActionCreator {
    return { dispatch in
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            dispatch(.populateMovies([Movie(title: "ABC")]))
        }
    
    }
}

class Store: ObservableObject {
    
    var reducer: Reducer
    @Published private (set) var appState: AppState
    
    init(appState: AppState, reducer: Reducer) {
        self.appState = appState
        self.reducer = reducer
    }
    
    func dispatch(_ dispatch: ActionCreator) {
        // how to send the movies to the reducer to update the state 
        //self.reducer.update(&appState, dispatch)
    }
}



// ContentView: 

store.dispatch(getMovies())
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason why do you want to use Redux Flow in SwiftUI? Why don't you do it in *pure* SwiftUI?

Comment: Redux flow allows for one point of change or truth. So, it makes it easier to debug things in the future.

Comment: How is it different than an `@EnvironmentObject`? It looks (at least for me) like you're overcomplicating things here...

Comment: Behind the scene I am using EnvironmentObject but keep in mind you cannot control the EnvironmentObject outside the view. So, Redux allows to maintain one store and only one way to update the store even inside non-view files. I suggest little reading on how Redux works.

Comment: For that I usually use DependencyInjection+EnvironmentObject. But I'll take a look at Redux as well.